# Excel Modified Vlookup for special data arrangment

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am trying to retrieve data from cells that are not in the same row or column as my search term.

EXAMPLE:

I want to populate cell `I5` (CO2 ppm start) based on the name `Humm_Control_S_AVG`
and the knowledge that I will find the data for CO2 ppm start 1 row down and 2 columns to the right of the name `Humm_Control_S_AVG` in my source data sheet.

In the images below I show a) the data to populate and b) the source datasheet

a) [efflux to populate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMLKB.png)

b) [source data sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUkQt.png)

---

**Note:** If it simplifies things, I can put the efflux data table to populate on the same sheet as the source data, although I would rather seperate them.

I think its not so complicated a problem, but having a hard time finding how to do this.

*THANKS!!!*

Answer (score 0):

Use `MATCH()` to search for the relative row or column position, offset it by 2 or 3.
Also take a look at OFFSET and INDIRECT

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a

Answer (score 0):

Thanks IceArdor,

The formula that solved this was:

```
=INDIRECT("'timeseries2'!D"&   MATCH($H5,timeseries2!$B$1:$B$848,0)+1)
```

1. `timeseries2` is the name of the sheet where the source data is
2. column D is the column location of the desired data to be retrieved in source data sheet
3. Match looks for `Humm_Control_S_AVG` and returns the row number where it is, I add 1 since to this number since the desired source data is 1 row below the search name